# pdfcrowd first page is always blank if the content is big

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation

I am stuck with this issue for so long days. I am trying to print the content in landscape but the first page is always blank but if the content fits to one page then it working correctly. Please help.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: $client->setPageWidth('297mm');
$client->setPageHeight('216mm');
$client->setVerticalMargin(96);

Comment: I have just used this setting. where PageHeight set the page correctly in landscape mode. But the first page is always blank and thereafter the content from 2nd page is correct.